# Loading assets from a gem in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

If I have a gem containing shared assets (sass, JavaScript, images etc) for a site, is there a straightforward way to pull those assets into a Jekyll build?

I know I could unpack the gem into the Jekyll project directory, but I was thinking there should be some way to access the assets having declared the dependency in the `[gems]` section of my `_config.yml`.